# Firebase database rules that prevent any write but only allow delete?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Is there any option to create a rule that prevent any writes or updates, but only allow delete nodes ?

My example is that i want to create cupon codes for game, so if i create a cupon in database, everyone will be able to read this and access it but when first person will use it in-game he will also delete this cupon in database. I can create that but in this case everyone can also create new nodes in database, and i dont want that because everyone can fully spam my base.

Hope anyone will understand what i mean.

Edit: i'm working in realtime db

Regards

Comment: Which database are you working with: Firestore or Realtime Database?

Comment: Realtime Database

Answer (score 0):

To allow writing initial data, and deleting data, but not updating it:

```
"(!data.exists() &&  newData.exists()) ||
 ( data.exists() && !newData.exists())"
```

Comment: I can get a cupon and cannot write with this but cant delete it.

Comment: Given how often I've written these rules, that seems unexpected. Can you try the deletion with just `data.exists() && !newData.exists()`. If that also doesn't work, can you show how you're deleting the node?

Comment: Please don't post a new answer, unless you have an... answer. Updates to your question should go into your... question. :)

Answer (score 0):

same results, cant delete, I tried a lot of combinations and noone works, and because of that i just ask here if there is maybe another option. if write is enabled i delete node after i get it:

```
private void PromoCodeDB()
{
    RestClient.Get<PromoCodeData>(codesDbURL + codeTextNum.text + ".json").Then(response =>
    {
        promoCodes = response;
        UpdateGold();
        Debug.Log("Code accepted");

        DeletePromoCodeDB();

    }).Catch(error =>
    {
        Debug.Log("Code does not exist.");
    });
}

private void DeletePromoCodeDB()
{
    RestClient.Delete(codesDbURL + codeTextNum.text + ".json").Then(response => {
        Debug.Log("Promo code deleted");
    }).Catch(error =>
    {
        Debug.Log("Cannot be deleted");
    });
}
```